# How to find all of the most common elements in a python list (order alphabetically in case of tie)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find all of the most common elements in a python list (order alphabetically in case of tie)
Suppose you have a list
'l = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c']'
the output should be
'''
a 2,
b 2
'''
I need a efficient solution of this in terms of time complexity.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but we are not gonna do your home work for you. What have you tried? what didnt work?

Comment: Look into `Counter` objects in the `collections` module.

Comment: I have looked into Counter and the most_common method as well. But it seems, I still have to use sorted() to get alphabetical ordering which makes the complexity nlogn.

Comment: @prin well sure, where `n` is *the number of ties*. No the size of the list. Are you seriously worried about a case where the number of ties is the same as the length of the list?

Comment: how else do you magically expect to have the list sorted by most common then alphabetically. You will need to sort the list somehow. Since Counter will count in the order is sees things why not just sort the list before you pass it `print(Counter(sorted(l)))`  giving `Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})`

Comment: I took a simple example here but it is not necessarily 1 character. It can be 'aa', 'abc' and so on. Basically, it is part of a scraping application where the elements of the list are userstrings.

Comment: So it this an actual problem you are trying to solve? Because then just use `sorted` on your list of ties. It will be fast

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: yes, juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @prin ok, then just use `counts = Counter(l)`, then `largest = max(counts.values())`, then `result = sorted([k for k,v in counts.items() if v == largest])`. That will be fast. As long as #ties << length(data) then this will be practically O(N)

Comment: okay @JonSG I will take care from next time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I get it. Although I read somewhere that dict are ordered alphabetically by default. Probably, I was mistaken.

Comment: @prin absolutely not correct at all. `dict` objects now maintain insertion order since Python 3.6+, but it has never been alphabetical. And it is usually good to think of dicts as *unordered*, although again, they maintain insertion order

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Would one not expect `sorted` to work faster on smaller lists such as the results of Counter() than on the full list?

Comment: @prin Are you looking for *the* most common item in the list unless there is a tie for "most common", or are you looking for the `n` most common items also taking ties into account?

Comment: @JonSG I am looking for the most common item in the list unless there is a tie for "most common"

Comment: @JonSG - yup didnt even give that a thought, the result of counter will always be smaller than the original list unless they were all unique. Good point

Comment: And what are the possible characters that can be used in the list? I mean, how many of them? It doesn't even make sense to say that ordering is nlogn if we're talking about a small constant number of characters. Let's say there can be 150000 possible different characters. That's also the max number of possible keys for the counter dictionary. And sorting 150000 elements can be done in, well, O(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (as discussed in the comments):

```
from collections import Counter

lst = # your list of characters
c = Counter(lst) # O(n)
largest = max(counts.values()) # O(n)
largest_with_ties = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == largest] # O(n)
result = sorted(largest_with_ties)
```

Now, what's the complexity of `sorted(largest_with_ties)`? One could say that it's O(nlogn) (because there could be n/2 ties). However, the number of characters in `largest_with_ties` cannot be as large as the number of elements in `lst`. And that's because there is a much smaller number of characters compared to the possible number of ints. In other words, `lst` could potentially contain 10^20 numbers (just an example). But `largest_with_ties` can only contain different characters, and the number of characters that can be represented (for example) with UTF8 is limited to more or less 10^6. Therefore, technically the complexity of this last operation is O(1). In general, we could say that it's O(nlogn) but with an upper limit of O(10^6log10^6).

Comment: For a `timeit` comparison see my answer. Spoiler yours is not any slower than mine and is quite a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to see if I could make @riccardo-bucco's answer any faster (I could not) but I will show you an alternative that is basically the same speed that I thought might be faster.

**To be clear, I feel the top answer is from @riccardo_bucco as it is easier to follow and is just as fast. Use it.**

I was hoping that not having to scan the counter twice would more than make up for resetting the largest_with_ties list, but it did not.

```
def jonsg(data_in):
    largest_with_ties = [(None, 0)]
    for item in collections.Counter(data_in).items():
        diff = item[1] - largest_with_ties[0][1]
        if diff < 0:
            continue
        if diff > 0:
            largest_with_ties.clear()
        largest_with_ties.append(item)
    return sorted(largest_with_ties)
```

Testing the timings I will use the words from "The Complete Works of William Shakespeare" from Project Guttenberg. You can get that here (5.5m): https://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt

Note, I have slightly altered Riccardo Bucco's answer to return a tuple not that it made a performance difference.

```py
import timeit

setup = """
import collections

#data_in = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c']
with open("shakespeare.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    data_in = [word.strip().lower() for line in file_in for word in line.split()]

def riccardo_bucco(data_in):
    counts = collections.Counter(data_in) # O(n)
    largest = max(counts.values()) # O(n)
    largest_with_ties = [item for item in counts.items() if item[1] == largest] # O(n)
    return sorted(largest_with_ties)

def jonsg(data_in):
    largest_with_ties = [(None, 0)]
    for item in collections.Counter(data_in).items():
        diff = item[1] - largest_with_ties[0][1]
        if diff < 0:
            continue
        if diff > 0:
            largest_with_ties.clear()
        largest_with_ties.append(item)
    return sorted(largest_with_ties)
"""
```

Now we can run:

```py
print(f"riccardo_bucco: {timeit.timeit('riccardo_bucco(data_in)', setup=setup, number=100)}")
print(f"jonsg         : {timeit.timeit('jonsg(data_in)', setup=setup, number=100)}")
```

giving results like:

```
riccardo_bucco: 10.59
jonsg         : 10.55
```

Suggesting to me that they perform equally well (or poorly). Feel free to extend this with other attempts.

FYI: The actual most common is: `('the', 30087)`.

If one wants to test with the individual characters then `data_in` can be set via:

```
data_in = [char.lower() for char in file_in.read() if char.strip()]
```

In that case the most common is `[('e', 482212)]`

But doing so does not fundamentally alter the relative performance of these solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Using your code and Counter we get the following:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_frequent(List):
    occurence_count = Counter(List)
    return occurence_count.most_common()

l = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c']


print(sorted(most_frequent(l)))
```

We get the output:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1)]
```

With sorted we sort the items automatically by alphabet.

You can double check that its sorting alphabetically with the following code:

```
tuplesInList = (most_frequent(l))
#to sort tuples within lists we use an anonymous function(lambda)
def sort_tuple_vals(my_tup):
    my_tup.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
    return my_tup
```

This sorts the tuples by the first element in the tuple

```
print(sort_tuple_vals(tuplesInList))
```

gets the output

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1)]
```

If you want to sort by occurrence as opposed to alphabetically, then sort by alphabetically in case of a tie, the following code should work. We first sort the tuples by the number of occurrences with lambda x: x[1]

```
tuplesInList = (most_frequent(l))
#to sort tuples within lists we use an anonymous function(lambda)
def sortTupsbyOccurance(my_tup):
    my_tup.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    print(my_tup)
    return my_tup

tuple=(sortTupsbyOccurance(tuplesInList))
print(tuple)
```

from an initial list l = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c'] we get the output:

```
[('c', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 3)]
```

using this I believe we solve the sorting by alphabet issue.
if tuple at position n's second value is equal to the second value of tuple at positon n+1 we note the equality and go to our next if statement with those values. Because we start at position 0 we are sure to not skip any potential matches.

```
#set the n value for  range 0, n to the number of tuple entries in the list.
for n in range(0,2):
        if tuple[n][1]==tuple[n+1][1]:
           print("there is an equality")
           var1=str(tuple[n][0])
           var2= str(tuple[n+1][0])

           if var1 > var2:
               print(var1, var2)
               print("this is true")
               # if tuple at position n's 1st value (alphabeticaly) is greater than tuple n+1's first value then we switch them.
              
               tuple[n], tuple[n+1] = tuple[n+1], tuple[n]
               print(tuple)
```

from initial list l with 3 "a"s and 3 "b"s we get the output:

```
[('c', 1), ('a', 3), ('b', 3)]
```

Comment: agreed after review, edited for clarification

Comment: Try with `l = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c']` to see you are not getting the requested output.

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying, but I also don't understand exactly what they're saying either. "Order alphabetically in case of a tie"... the current order is ordered alphabetically. If they want it ordered not alphabetically but by occurance they could use the tuple sort function to return sorted by x[1] and then us an if == statement to sort by the alphabetical statement. Do you suggest I change answer to this or? I answered given what I thought they were asking but I see the confusion

Comment: With your input, the answer they want would be `[('b', 3)]`. With their input the answer they seek is `[('a', 2), ('b', 2)]`. The tied most common letters (two occurrences, each) presented alphabetically `a` before `b`.

Comment: I agree- I changed the code to reflect the answer they seek